# angular 1.5 controller not displaying text

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to learn angular 1.5 and i am having difficulty getting the controller to display the text on the webpage. It display event.name instead of what is in the controller.

This is EventDetails.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="eventsApp">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Event Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="EventController">
        {{event.name}}
    </div>
    </div>
   <script scr="/lib/jquery.min.js"/>
   <script scr="/lib/underscore-1.4.4.min.js"/>
   <script scr="/lib/boostrap.min.js"/>
   <script scr="/lib/angular/angular.min.js"/>
   <script scr="/js/app.js"/>
   <script scr="/js/controllers/EventController.js"/>
   </body>
   </html>
```

my app.js

```
var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp',[]);
```

EventController

```
'use strict';

eventsApp.controller('EventController',
function EventController($scope) {
    $scope.event = {
        name: 'Angular Boot Camp',
        time: '10:30 am',
        date: '1/1/2013'
        }

    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your controller should be,

```
eventsApp.controller('EventController',
function($scope) {
    $scope.event = {
        name: 'Angular Boot Camp',
        time: '10:30 am',
        date: '1/1/2013'
        }

    }
);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var eventsApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
eventsApp.controller('EventController', function($scope){
  $scope.event = {
        name: 'Angular Boot Camp',
        time: '10:30 am',
        date: '1/1/2013'
        } ;
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="EventController">
     <div class="container">        
         <h1> {{event.name}}  </h1>     
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried that solution and it did not work. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: it displays on the webpage {{event,name}} instead of Angular Boot Camp

Comment: did you run the demo check output?

Comment: sorry i do not understand what you mean by demo check output

Comment: click the button run code snippet in the above answer and see

Comment: Your demo works fine but i am using webstorm IDE and following a pluralsight video.

Comment: It does not have to do anything with the ide

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `ng-app="myApp"` declaration on your html which is why your angular app is not running.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reverse the scripts loading order in your EventDetails.html.

app.js should be loaded last.

The right order should be:

```
   <script scr="/js/controllers/EventController.js"/>
   <script scr="/js/app.js"/>
```

and you should adopt the other comments as well, adding ng-app annotation (@geofrey comment) and refactoring your controller (@Sajeetharan comment)

Answer (score 0):

Use "src" attribute instead "scr" (not "script scr=...") in script tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="eventsApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Event Registration</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div ng-controller="EventController">
                {{event.name}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp',[]);

            'use strict';

            eventsApp.controller('EventController', function EventController($scope) {
                $scope.event = {
                    name: 'Angular Boot Camp',
                    time: '10:30 am',
                    date: '1/1/2013'
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```